# Unable to start "IntegrationApp" on iOS 14.6 through Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to install IntegrationApp on iPad with iOS 14.6 version through Xcode and as I do Product > Run as shown below, I am getting unable to install "IntegrationApp". [image]

Below is the error that I am encountering,

[image: Here is the error that shows as]

When I hit details on the error pop up, it looked like this,
[image]

I had no issues or errors from signing & capabilities and development team selection.
I am able to install WebDriverAgentRunner but not IntegrationApp. Apart from system information displayed on bottom of the error screenshot, device information is as follows,

iOS device iPad (7th generation)

OS Version: 14.6

Any leads please ?

Comment: What is this "IntegrationApp"?

Comment: IntegrationApp is a sample app that comes with Appium installation.

Comment: Facing the same error, @GSN,  Are you able to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Facing same error. @GSN did you resolve this error?